# Extract data from very variable Strings

Tags: php, algorithm, detection, extract, data-extraction

I hope you can help me on creating an algorithm.
What I need is to extract data from a String inputted by a human (someone who doesn't really care that I have to do that). In this string he puts language requirements. The data is already there, so it's sadly too late to ask the user to input this correctly. The Strings may look like these:

```
"English   good   arabic   good   german   basic knowledges"

"good in english, a little bit german"

"english, german"

"english - very good, german - preferred"
```

now i only want to focus on german end english here. I would like to know wether they are required or not, and, if possible, by how much (maybe by a grade form 1 - "know it a little bit" to 5 - "be perfect at it")

I thought of an algorithm splitting the string into words (thats not the problem) and then looping through them, detecting if this word means german or english (probably by some regex like `/(deu|ger)/Ui` and `/(eng)/Ui`) and then getting the level of the requirement (here comes the tricky part), which should stand somewhere in the following or previous words (or it isn't there at all).

Do you have any ideas on how to create such a functionality?

It should run on PHP7 btw, but it's about the idea of the algorithm here, not the implementation (yet).

Comment: Better to force consistent input than try to decipher any imaginable combination.

Comment: It's too late sadly. The Database is already filled. It doesn't have to be perfect at all. I just want detection if possible.

Answer (score 1):

This method use fuzzy set theory and may work only for 80%. It's not that bad, because any fuzzy algorithm supposes outliers in datasets.

Your examples can be described as

`LANG1` + `separator` + `LANG2` + `separator`

where

`LANG` = `NAME` + `adjective` or `adjective` + `NAME`

`separator` = `,` `;` `.` or even may be virtual.

To parse `NAME` and `adjective` you have to use approximate string matching.

My observations:

1. `LANG1` is better than `LANG2`
2. `LANG` may contain an adjective
3. some adjectives may break observation 1. (I think it can be checked by several "if" statement)
4. some adjectives can be used to estimate the level of knowledge
5. In case when `separator` between `LANG1` and `LANG2` is virtual we can add `;` right after the moment when `NAME1` get `adjective1` or right before the moment when `NAME2` is found

To get an estimation of knowledge level you have to:

1. Estimate top100 eng adjectives by hand using values from `[0;1]` - this process called fuzzification of linguistic variables
2. Find an appropriate categories ("good", "bad", "pre-intermediate", "native", etc.) and membership functions to distinguish those estimations into understandable linguistic forms - this process called [defuzzification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defuzzification)
3. Apply all possible rules (in terms of step 2.) that you can use to estimate the knowledge as `1,2,3,4,5`
4. Defuzzify (mb it's better to say "aggregate") the result of step 3 into integer `1,2,3,4,5` for english and german languages (separately)

In case you have some additional information about users that may help on step 3 (just as I did it in observation 1) - I think you should find some more observations because the estimation with adjactives is rather subjective. For example, if the age of your users is under 14 - there is no chance to find "advanced" speaker I think, but if your site is called "German for youngsters" - he still may get "5".

PS In case you'll get any positive results it may be a good material for academic publication!))